# No inspect views option on my Chrome extension manifest v3

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension

I don't have the inspect views option on my google chrome extension that I am working on.

[image]

And this is my manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "hoko's ext",
    "description": "my ext",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html" 
      },
      "permissions": [
        "activeTab"
      ],
      "background": {
        "service-worker": "background.js",
        "type": "module"

      },
      "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["https://*/*"],
          "js": ["content.js"]
        }
      ]
  
}
```

Comment: Replace `-` with `_` in `service-worker`.

Comment: Thanks! It worked, I can't believe I spent days reworking my code and all it needed was the replacement. Made a really big difference.